# Null Pointer Exception while retrieving data from SQLite and displaying in listview

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to display the contents of a database in a listview. While running the code I am getting NullPointerException and my application is getting crashed. Please see the following code:

helper.java:

```
public String[] personslist() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase myDB;
        int i=0;
         String[] values = {};
        try {
                  myDB=this.openDataBase();                   
              Cursor c=myDataBase.rawQuery("select PersonName from Persons;",null);
               if (c != null ) {
                     if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                     do {

                         // put your code to get data from cursor                      



                        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                               values[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PersonName"));
                               i++;
                            }
                        }while (c.moveToNext());
                     }
                  }
                  if(c != null)
                  {
                     myDB.close();
                     c.close();
                  }                    
                  }catch(SQLException sqle){

                  throw sqle;
                  }
         return values;
         }
```

the method openDatabase():

```
 public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    return myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }
```

This is the code I have used to display the items in listview.

```
 public class newlist extends ListActivity {
    final adapter info = new adapter(this);
    String[] y = info.plist();
 /*   private static final String[] GENRES = new String[] {
        "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama",
        "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"
    };*/

    private ListView listView = null;
    private MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = null;
    private boolean editMode = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.listView = getListView();
        this.myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, y);
        this.setListAdapter(this.myArrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();

        MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();

        if(!this.editMode) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        } else {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit, menu);
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.edit_menu_item) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "entering edit mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            this.editMode = true;
            this.listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            this.listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

            this.myArrayAdapter.setEditMode(editMode);
        } else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.commit_menu_item 
                || item.getItemId() == R.id.cancel_menu_item) {
            if(item.getItemId() == R.id.commit_menu_item) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "committing changes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "leaving edit mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            this.editMode = false;
            this.listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
            this.listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
            this.listView.clearChoices();

            this.myArrayAdapter.setEditMode(editMode);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        if(!this.editMode) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "list item selected at position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String str = "";
            SparseBooleanArray wtfit = l.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                if(wtfit.get(i)) {
                    str += i + ", ";
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected item positions: " + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private Context context;
        private String[] entires;

        private boolean editMode = false;

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] entries) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item, entries);

            this.context = context;
            this.entires = entries;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
            final ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if(view == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                viewHolder.text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                viewHolder.checkbox1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.text1.setText(this.entires[position] + "_1");
            viewHolder.text2.setText(this.entires[position] + "_2");
            viewHolder.checkbox1.setChecked(listView.isItemChecked(position));

            if(this.editMode) {
                viewHolder.checkbox1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.checkbox1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return view;
        }

        public void setEditMode(boolean editMode) {
            this.editMode = editMode;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView text1;
            TextView text2;
            CheckBox checkbox1;
        }
    }
}
```

And the logcat is,

```
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fromstart/com.example.fromstart.newlist}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.example.fromstart.adapter.plist(adapter.java:131)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.example.fromstart.newlist.<init>(newlist.java:26)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
09-09 05:57:05.687: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Put some exception log.

Comment: how are you opening the database? Put openDataBase() source code.

Comment: post your code here also where you have tried to set your data in listview.

Comment: What is `myDataBase`. I think it should be `myDB`.

Comment: NPE in `adapter.plist()` on row 131, called by `newlist` constructor. Your code snippet does not include those.

Comment: your code is not the code that caused the exception. (plist != personslist)

Comment: friends, thank you very much for your suggestions. Please have a look at the updated post. I have added the logcat, opendatabase method and the listview activity.

Comment: @laalto, newlist is another class, from which I am calling this method from the adapter class.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07, I have tried both myDB and myDataBase. both are returning the same error.

Comment: @njzk2, why plist != personslist ?

Comment: I think `adapter` is a class... Post its code.

Comment: yes @AnujMathur_07, adapter is a class. but I cannot post or update the code here. sorry for that.

Comment: Post adapter class's code.

Comment: @nki : your exception is in plist. the code you posted mentions only personslist

Comment: what is at adapter.java:131 ?

Comment: There I am calling this method - `public adapter open() throws SQLException
 {
  mDbHelper = new helper(mContext);
  mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  return this;
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things. First is your array initialization. The line

```
String[] values = {};
```

creates an empty array without allocated memory. You need to initialize an array with the size to hold all elements you are going to store in the array.
e.g. after the query do

```
String[] values = new String[c.getCount()];
```

Then it seems you are calling `c.moveToNext()` too often. Once in your for loop and then in the surrounding do-while.

Simply do something like

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
     values[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PersonName"));
     i++;
}
```

Comment: as per your suggestion, I have changed the code. But, now also I am getting the same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class newlist extends ListActivity {
    final adapter info = new adapter(this);
    String[] y = info.plist();
```

Looks like the problem is here. You're trying to use the `Activity` as a `Context` when the `newlist` object is initialized. You cannot do that until `onCreate()`.  Move your `adapter` initialization and `plist()` call, whatever that is, to `onCreate()` to fix it.